# SQL Retrieving repeated rentals

Tags: mysql, sql

Question:

> write a SQL query that retrieves repeated rentals in which the same 
>   customer rents the same movie more than once. if a customer rents the > same movie multiple times, the output should show this (customer's name, movie's title) combination only once

There are 3 tables:

- customer table: (id, name, country, created_date)
- movie table: (id, title, duration, release_year)
- rental table: (id, customer_id, movie_id)

i currently have:

```
select customer.name, movie.title
from ((rental inner join customer on rental.customer_id = customer.id) inner join movie on rental.movie_id = movie.id)
group by customer.name, movie.title
having count(*) > 1;
```

but it is incorrect - any thoughts?

Comment: don't edit your question to remove the substance of it after you get an answer. SO questions aren't just for you, they're for the whole community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT c.name, m.title
FROM rental AS r
  INNER JOIN customer AS c ON r.customer_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN movie AS m ON r.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY c.name, m.title
HAVING count(*) > 1
;
```

Your `JOIN` statements has wrong syntax

EDIT: to avoid naming duplicates change `GROUP BY` statements:

```
GROUP BY c.id, m.id
```

Comment: interesting, i tried it and it is still incorrect. there are two test cases - 1) output dimension (13 rows, 2 columns) and 2) correct answer.....so i am only passing case 2 and for case 1 i am getting 14 rows, 2 columns........when i do SELECT customer_id, movie_id from rental GROUP BY customer_id, movie_id HAVING count(*) > 1; i pass both cases. this query checks the repeated rentals but just doesnt retrieve the respective customer and movie names and title. any thoughts? i have added more details to what columns the tables have. RENTAL table also has an id field

Comment: Try to add `SELECT c.name, m.title, COUNT(*)` and compare with your counts. Or better use `GROUP BY c.id, m.id`, because you can have duplicate names

Comment: sweet thanks! i tried the GROUP BY c.id, m.id and it worked.

Comment: Generally you have to GROUP BY the thing you SELECT, so ignore the edit.